# set completeopt=noinsert fails

Tags: autocompletion, set

I use the auto complete function from [this stackoverflow page](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8902).
It works fine on my pc and notebook but it fails on my raspberry pi with this error:

```
line   28:
E474: Invalid argument: completeopt=menu,menuone,noinsert
```

Why doesn't it work?
Whats the problem ?

Comment: It's `noselect`.

Answer (score 8):

The `noinsert` option became available with Vim version 7.4.775. Your Vim on the raspberry pi is (probably) older. You can check with `:version`.